# Cross Compile ncurses application for ARM linux

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, ncurses

I want to cross compile an application from my workstation (x86, linux) for an ARM application processor. First I build for my system:

```
gcc -static -g -Wall -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -g -Wall main.o -o myApplication -lncurses
```

this build like I want and also work. If I want to build this for arm

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -g -Wall -c main.c -o main.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -g -Wall main.o -o myApplication -lncurses
```

But this will not compile.

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses
collect2: Error
```

So: how to cross-compile a ncurses Application in this way?

Comment: Where's your ARM version of the ncurses library located? Unless you've tried to put it somewhere covered by the cross-linker's default search path, you'll need to tell the thing where to find it. The one in /usr/lib/... is full of x86 code.

Comment: I search for it in all my directories but cannot find it. Do I have to build ncurses for arm on my self or are there any package or ppa for this (ppa)?

Comment: Really, the best thing to do when cross-compiling is to mount the target device's filesystem on the host machine (or just keep a copy of it there) and build against that with `--sysroot=`. After all, if _that_ doesn't have the correct libraries, then your dynamically-linked program isn't going to run there anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to do it would be to download a binary release of [ELLCC](http://ellcc.org). It comes with a pre-built libraries, including ncurses. The download page is [here](http://ellcc.org/blog/?page_id=20295). If you grab e.g. http://ellcc.org/releases/ellcc-x86_64-linux-eng-0.1.27.tgz (The version number will change over time), you can untar it. For the ARM, your build lines would look like:

```
~/ellcc/bin/ecc -target arm-linux-engeabihf -g -Wall -c main.c -o main.o
~/ellcc/bin/ecc -target arm-linux-engeabihf -g -Wall main.o -o myApplication -lncurses
```

It creates a static binary, so you don't have to worry about shared library versions.

Comment: Thank you @richard, your answer helped me!